# Javascript file loads twice

Tags: cakephp

In my view, when I call inline execution `<?php echo $this->Html->script('forms/contact');?>` it executes okay, but when I want the script to be loaded within the head tags it generates the code twice.

In my view:

```
<?php $this->Html->script('forms/contact', array('inline' => false));?>
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/animalmedica/js/forms/contact.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/animalmedica/js/forms/contact.js"></script>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Just some ideas: are you sure your code is not inside some kind of loop? Also: in your view are you maybe including some other blocks/elements? Maybe you load your script even in your layout?

Comment: try removing the first line from your view to see if you still get an output. If you get it then may be it is coming from somewhere(maybe header file if you have included one)

Comment: Are you relying on `$scripts_for_layout` in your layout? You'll need to check [how many times you're appending to the script block](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L559), or [how you're appending to the `script` block twice with the same content](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/ViewBlock.php#L151). Since by default [it's not possible to append the same script twice](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L540-L543) calling it twice isn't a likely cause.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on vacation... Yes, I rely on `$scripts_for_layout`... and when I remove the line from the view (where I make the call) it disappears completely. The view being called twice is illogical, cause it is the current controller -> action view. Quite confusing... it works both ways, but I just wanted to understand why it happens. Currently I am working on another project, I'll come back to this problem further... if I find the cause I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your question as to why, but I had exactly the same issue. After some trial and error I came up with this solution:

In my default layout I was using both the fetch script method and scripts for layout. I only needed one

```
echo $this->Html->charset(); 
echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
echo $this->Html->css('grid_layout');
echo $this->Html->css('style');
echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom');
echo $this->Html->script('countdown');
echo $this->Html->script('page');
echo $this->fetch('meta');
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=>FALSE));
//echo $scripts_for_layout;
```

scripts for layout is now deprecated:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files